3D modelling from LIDAR data using QGIS
I'm trying to generate a 3D model of a city using LiDAR data and building footprints (.shp). Unfortunately, my LiDAR data isn't very dense—it's only 1 point per square meter.
I'm using QGIS to process the LiDAR data (I think Delaunay triangulation might be the best option, but I'm not getting great results so maybe I'm wrong) and then planning to use Rhino3D for the actual city modeling.
Any advice?

What is the problem your the results?

The interpolation is not that good... and in the other hand I didn't achieve to do a 3d model of the roofs.

I think a more generalized solution will work best here. I do not advise that you vectorize your lidar data, keeping it in raster format is preferable.
One simple solution would be to use the raster calculator and separate any values that are above a certain height threshold and are likely to be buildings, such as 3m.
Another solution would be to rasterise your polygons to the same dimensions as your lidar dem and then use it to mask/extract from the dem

Thanks! I will try, my concern is that I will need as a final result a simplified model of the building (I mean like simple and straight geometries) and maybe this process doesn't achieve that result, for that reason i was thinking about the .shp generation. Any idea abt that? (hope i have explained well...)

You won't be able to extract straight lines from the dem where they do not exist already. You'll have to make them. I would suggest you use the zonal stats tool to get the maximum dem height for each building footprint. Then rasterise the polygons using the max height values. Use raster calculator to set the dem values to the building raster value where the datasets intersect
